# Xpages - Fulltext search on a view with pager

Tags: xpages

I have a scenario. I am using a viewpanel with a pager. I have bound a search box to viewscope and filer view using viewscope value. Its all fine. Now, I have a column value which displays on first page. Now if I go to next page using pager and search, resulting view is filtered and does not display any row unless I use pager. So it looks like view is filtered only results on current page will be displayed. I can navigate to another results using pager only.
I am sure this should not be the case but can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Please add your code to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting the Pager with `pager.gotoFirst()` after you've searched.